# Regsvr32 not exiting

Tags: c++, dll, regsvr32

I'm registering a dll using regsvr32, after registering is successful regsvr32 still remains in task manager so i'm not able to register another dll without killing it.
I took over the work from someone else, so where should i start looking for in the program that generated dll to fix the problem.

Comment: You'll have to debug your DllRegisterServer() function.  Project > Properties > Debugging > Command = "regsvr32.exe", Command Arguments = $(TargetPath)

Answer (score 4):

Regsvr32 just load the dll and call a specific exported function, so the "hang" is probably not related with Regsvr32 itself, but with the dll you are trying to register.